# ComandoIf - Programa não retorna valores

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, pandas, if, dataframe

Olá,

Esta me tomando um tempo para descobrir onde estou errando. Gostaria de comparar as colunas de duas tabelas excel (uma na planilha 1 e outra na planilha2). A tabela é a seguinte:

tabela coilid
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3kRg.png

tabela retifica
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30kzy.png

Eu quero comparar os campos DT_START da coilid, com os campos Data de entrada e Data de saída, da tabela retifica.
Se DT_START estiver entre os valores Data de entrada e Data de Saída, então concatenar as linhas das duas tabelas.

```
import pandas as pd

retifica = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
coilid = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha2')


match=pd.DataFrame()
for x in range (coilid.shape[0]):
    for y in range (retifica.shape[0]):
        if (coilid.iloc[x,1]>retifica.iloc[y,17])&(coilid.iloc[x,1]<retifica.iloc[y,18]):
            matchaux = [coilid.iloc[x],retifica.iloc[y]]
            match=match.append(matchaux)
    break
    
    match.head()
```

Só que o programa roda mas não retorna o match.head(). Daí, eu peguei os dados da tabela das datas, coloquei valores semelhantes e mesmo assim, nada.

O que eu estou errando?

Desde já agradeço,

PS: coilid tem 1084 linhas e retifica tem 2964.

Answer (score -3):

Primeiramente, nas próximas perguntas forneça um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e não as imagens das tabelas que você forneceu. Abaixo vou mostrar como criá-los.

#### Dados de exemplo

Como você informou que há pouco mais de 1000 registros na **coilid** para quase 3000 na **retifica** estou criando um exemplo de 1 por 3 respectivamente.

Os dados foram criados utilizando a biblioteca [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) porém para evitar um código longo e confuso estou mostrando somente a criação com os valores.

Outro ponto é que a data está no [formato interno do Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). Eu não entendi o motivo já que o Pandas consegue converter normalmente esse formato para o formato de de tempo. Mas utilizando a biblioteca [xlrd](https://www.python-excel.org/) consegui manter o padrão.

##### 1. Dados coilid:

```py
df_coilid = pd.DataFrame({
    'cd_coil': ['I711220186_8', 'I833969477_5', 'C591795330_4', 'D352560123_0', 'S891013991_6'],
    'dt_start': [44991.42488425926, 45018.4750462963, 44993.80498842592, 44986.07134259259, 45041.32665509259]
})
```

```
        cd_coil      dt_start
0  I711220186_8  44991.424884
1  I833969477_5  45018.475046
2  C591795330_4  44993.804988
3  D352560123_0  44986.071343
4  S891013991_6  45041.326655
```

##### 2. Dados retifica:

```py
df_retifica = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    'data_entrada': [45013.58841435185, 45021.98451388889, 45021.51755787037, 45018.552569444444, 45035.8025462963, 45022.76053240741, 45015.5034375, 45013.64405092593, 45038.95806712963, 45033.19980324074, 45017.46540509259, 45025.15592592592, 45015.936435185184, 45023.258263888885, 45016.03194444445],
    'data_saida': [45028.20349537037, 45030.48704861111, 45032.10207175926, 45022.92935185185, 45036.54336805556, 45034.98509259259, 45038.18040509259, 45015.55569444445, 45039.57046296296, 45041.68699074074, 45036.45997685185, 45029.99480324074, 45028.5646412037, 45031.96131944445, 45038.858668981484]
})
```

```
    num  data_entrada    data_saida
0     1  45013.588414  45028.203495
1     2  45021.984514  45030.487049
2     3  45021.517558  45032.102072
3     4  45018.552569  45022.929352
4     5  45035.802546  45036.543368
5     6  45022.760532  45034.985093
6     7  45015.503438  45038.180405
7     8  45013.644051  45015.555694
8     9  45038.958067  45039.570463
9    10  45033.199803  45041.686991
10   11  45017.465405  45036.459977
11   12  45025.155926  45029.994803
12   13  45015.936435  45028.564641
13   14  45023.258264  45031.961319
14   15  45016.031944  45038.858669
```

#### Solução

```py
data = []
for _, x in df_coilid.iterrows():
    for _, y in df_retifica.iterrows():
        if (y['data_entrada'] < x['dt_start'] < y['data_saida']):
            matched = pd.concat([x, y])
            data.append(matched)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Não encontrei uma forma menos custosa para processar o método mas consegui reduzi bastante a verbosidade do código usando o método [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). O método `iterrows()` itera o *DataFrame* linha a linha não precisando que você utilize o `iloc`.

Precisamos informar dentro do `for` uma variável adicional `_` pois ela é o índice da linha e não precisamos utilizá-la e as variáveis `x` e `y` são os valores das colunas.

Você pode usar a [lógica de comparação encadeada](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) no `if` para encontrar os valores de `dt_start` que está entre `data_entrada` e `data_saida`. Isso é somente uma forma de refatorar o código mas sua lógica está correta.

Outro ponto é nunca preencher um *DataFrame* com novas linhas. É preferível armazenar os valores numa lista como é visto na variável `data` e depois transformar essa lista em um *DataFrame*.

Abaixo temos os resultados:

```
        cd_coil      dt_start  num  data_entrada    data_saida
0  I833969477_5  45018.475046    1  45013.588414  45028.203495
1  I833969477_5  45018.475046    7  45015.503438  45038.180405
2  I833969477_5  45018.475046   11  45017.465405  45036.459977
3  I833969477_5  45018.475046   13  45015.936435  45028.564641
4  I833969477_5  45018.475046   15  45016.031944  45038.858669
5  S891013991_6  45041.326655   10  45033.199803  45041.686991
```

Convertendo em data temos:

```
        cd_coil    dt_start  num data_entrada  data_saida
0  I833969477_5  02/04/2023    1   28/03/2023  12/04/2023
1  I833969477_5  02/04/2023    7   30/03/2023  22/04/2023
2  I833969477_5  02/04/2023   11   01/04/2023  20/04/2023
3  I833969477_5  02/04/2023   13   30/03/2023  12/04/2023
4  I833969477_5  02/04/2023   15   31/03/2023  22/04/2023
5  S891013991_6  25/04/2023   10   17/04/2023  25/04/2023
```

### Veja mais

- [python - Convert Excel style date with pandas - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/6600992)
- [python - Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746204/6600992)
- [How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409168/6600992)

Comment: Não entendi onde não funcionou. Me respondam pra que eu possa melhorar.